# cakePHP returns old (out of date) data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Everything was working perfect, sudenly (without any modification), the queries started to return old (out of date) data.

I delete a record, it takes a time (few seconds) to return the data without this record.
I insert a new record, it takes a time to return the data with this new record.

Any help?

An example:

```
    public function getResidentsByResidenciaId($id = null) {
    $resident = $this->Residents->find('all', [
            'conditions' => ['Residents.residencia_id =' => $id],
            'contain' => ['Usuarios']
    ]);

    $this->set('resident', $resident);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['resident']);
}
```

edited:
I have this configurarion:

```
Router::extensions('xml');
Router::extensions('json');
Router::defaultRouteClass('DashedRoute');
```

and I´m using ".json" in the end of the URL.

Testing, I realized that when I change de DB (CRUD) and I access the cakePHP without ".json", in normal way (showing the dev-toobar), it brings me correct, with ".json", it takes a few seconds to upgrade.

Comment: Add your code here

Comment: Does clearing the cache in the dev-toolbar cause the right data to load right away?

Comment: If you mean CTRL+SHIFT+DEL in firefox, nope, does not work. If I wait few seconds and reload it, it returns the correct list. I tried "incognito mode" in Chrome and did not work too.

Comment: I mean the dev toolbar (the yellow icon in the bottom right of the screen) if it doesn't show there try setting your `debug`-config  to `true` or installing it following the steps at https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit

Comment: The code in the question will not exhibit what you describe unless you have a behavior caching data or similar. Either you have a misunderstanding, or you need to add to the questio the code responsible for caching (and returning stale) data.

Comment: @AD7six, i didn´t set any cache behaviour. I´m thinking it can be a server side problem. My "localhost" (test) works perfectly, but the cloud host (copy of localhost) is getting this problem, and as I said, suddenly. The cloud server was working perfectly too.

Comment: I edited the post above with some new tests.

Comment: Despite some conflicting statements, it sounds like you browser cache (http cache headers). You need to demonstrate your problem, not describe it; use e.g. curl to see the actual response headers and add that to the question.